# remove jsessionid cookie from browser at that time session is going to invalidate

Tags: java, session, cookies

I am creating one web application in java. I am using session for this application. when i deleting cookie from browser at that time my session is invalidate. i want to prevent that thing.
for ex: 
when you are logging in banking website. after logged in website you remove cookie from browser you are still logging in website.
Anyone know how to store session of user when clear the cookies.

Comment: why use cookies and sessions?

Comment: i am using session for details of logged in user.

Comment: and what are you using cookies for?

Comment: I detect a `code smell`

Comment: i am not using cookie. when we are creating a session at that time jsessionid cookie will be automatically generated at client browser.

Comment: Yes, the underlying web server will do this for you.  If you user is silly enough to remove the cookies, I belive that the session will no longer be valid and they will no longer be logged in.

Comment: Yes, that i know. but read my question. In banking website we are still logged in when we delete the cookies from browser. so i want that concept in my application.

Comment: With no extra code, when I delete my jseesionid cookie, I will no longer be logged in.  Are you meaning that you want to take some action when a session expires?

Comment: No, I want to user to be still logged in application when user deletes the cookies from browser.

Comment: try finding a web application server that does not store its session in cookies then

Comment: Right now i am using jboss 5.1.0 ga application server. i have no brief idea about this can you please give some more suggestion.

Answer (score -1):

There is no way to. If the user deletes cookies, there is no way to identify him in subsequent requests.

There are some "hacky" ways to do it (for example [this](http://www.programmerinterview.com/index.php/php-questions/can-sessions-work-without-cookies/)), but I don't recommend you to do this. What's the reason to? Cookies are standard.

Comment: this is a comment not an answer